# Oracle applying indexes to improve this query

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

Hi I am having issues applying indexes to improve the speed of the following query..

```
   SELECT SUM(OL.QTY) FROM ORDER_LINE OL, PRODUCT P, ORDERS O 
   WHERE
   O.O_DATE BETWEEN '01-FEB-2014' AND '28-FEB-2014'
   AND
   O.ID = OL.ORDER_ID
   AND
   P.ID = OL.PRODUCT_ID
   AND
   P.NAME = 'APRICOT JAM'
   ;
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated! Currently I have tried applying a concatenated index to the orders table as (O_DATE,ID) which hasn't helped much!

The tables designs are below! Thankyou!

```
  ORDERS
  ID         NOT NULL     NUMBER(38)
  CUSTID     NOT NULL     NUMBER(38)
  O_DATE     NOT NULL     DATE

  ORDER_LINE
  ORDER_ID   NOT NULL     NUMBER(38)
  PRODUCT_ID NOT NULL     NUMBER(38)
  QTY        NOT NULL     NUMBER(4)

  PRODUCT
  ID         NOT NULL     NUMBER(38)
  NAME       NOT NULL     VARCHAR(30)
  PRICE      NOT NULL     NUMBER(3,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create index for this fields

```
PRODUCT.NAME

ORDER_LINE.PRODUCT_ID
ORDER_LINE.ORDER_ID

ORDERS.O_DATE
```

I assume that you have already primary key fields. If not, create unique index for primary keys first

```
ORDER.ID
PRODUCT.ID
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, I have tried to apply an index to the O_DATE value but the optimizer seems to not use this and when I include a hint it the query decreases performance drastically. I used a btree index for it in this scenario, any advice?

Comment: Oracle decides using indexes by data and statistics. Your data may have faster results on full table scan so oracle optimizer decides not using the index.

Comment: If you create indexes above, you may probably get faster results. O_date may not be used but index on product.name can decrease your execution time.

Comment: The product one works, thanks :) but Im having issues with this O_Date one I just dont understand why the optimizer wont use it!